# Laravel whereJsonContains query

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

I have following JSON code in my database table

```
    [
  {
    "indentifier": "category",
    "name": "XXXXXXX",
    "products": [
      {
        "indentifier": "childproduct",
        "name": "XXXX",
        "price": 15,
        "sku": "+0094",
        "factorynumber": "156670",
        "unit": "50 Stk/Pck",
        "kp": "50",
        "discountCode": "V",
        "from": "2020-01-01",
        "to": "2099-01-01"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "indentifier": "category",
    "name": "XXXXXXX",
    "products": [
      {
        "indentifier": "childproduct",
        "name": "XXXX",
        "price": 29,
        "sku": "+0104",
        "factorynumber": "156680",
        "unit": "50 Stk/Pck",
        "kp": "50",
        "discountCode": "V",
        "from": "2020-01-01",
        "to": "2099-01-01"
      },
      ....
    ]
  }
]
```

Now how I can implement for searching the sku in this JSON in "when" keyword? My following code is here:

```
        $date =  now()->toDateString();
        if ($request->keyword != "") {
            $keyword = $request->keyword;
        } else {
            $keyword = false;
        }

$products = Product::whereJsonContains('catalogs', intval($request->catalog))
            ->whereDate('from', '<=', $date)
            ->whereDate('to', '>', $date)
            ->orderBy('category', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('sort', 'ASC')
            ->where('active', 1)
            })
            ->when(
                $keyword,
                function ($query, $keyword) use ($category) {
                    $query->where('sku', 'like', '%' . $keyword)
                        ->orWhere('factorynumber', 'like', $keyword)
                        ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')
                        ->orWhereJsonContains('childs', ['products->sku' => $keyword])
                        ->where('active', 1)
                        });
                }
            )->get();
```

The line with

```
->orWhereJsonContains('childs', ['products->sku' => $keyword])
```

will not work... what is the right syntax for the query? At moment there are 0 results if search for child sku field.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

`orWhereJsonContains()` doesn't exist in Laravel, but `whereJsonContains()`, and it works with arrays and not the associative arrays. Also you have to make sure the data from json goes as the first argument, not the second like this:

```
whereJsonContains('table_column_name_with_json_in_it->json_value_key',$requiredValue)
```

In that case this query of yours:

```
->orWhereJsonContains('childs', ['products->sku' => $keyword])
```

Should be something like this:

```
->WhereJsonContains('product->sku', $sku)
```

Comment: I can't understand how it returned the results instead of throwing exception when you used ```orWhereJsonContains()``` can you share the docs with me where you read about this method